# Python script prints but has no terminal

Tags: python, shell, unix, background-process

I have an old python script that includes `print` commands. Sometimes I need to run this script in the background with no terminal associated (I think). Sometimes the script crashes. Could this be the reason? What would a solution be?

I described this badly. Here is what happens:
I run the script with & at the end from a terminal window. It works fine. I then close the window. It crashes.

Comment: This is beyond vague; could *what* be the reason? Printing unicode data without encoding explicitly when stdout is redirected to /dev/null can cause errors, for example, but so can a million other things.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The fact that I am calling `print` with no terminal to print to

Comment: Whichever terminal you call the script from becomes the terminal to which it is associated. Unless `stdout` is explicitly redirected, the terminal window is `stdout`

Comment: Code sample and error output would be great.

Comment: Is there any correlation between running without a terminal and crashing? Or are we just adrift in a sea of vague?

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash, when calling the script from a terminal ? What does the stacktrace tell you ?

Comment: @DonalFellows Sorry. Yes, when I run the script, even in the background, it works fine. When the terminal window is closed, it crashes.

Comment: Are you sure it crashes and doesn't just receive some signal? Have you tried running it as `nohup python script.py &`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script does not crash but is terminated by the closing terminal.

You need to start the script using the `nohup` command:

```
$ nohup ./myscript.py &
```

Even better (if you want to catch the output to stdout):

```
$ nohup ./myscript.py > myscript.log &
```